# How to use PID control for line following robot?

Tags: pid, line-following

It's me the greatest noob again.thank you very much for your last help guys.Now,this time I am with a line following robot.I want to use PID control in it.But I'm not getting any perfect resource from where I can learn it.I want to be fluent with it and learn it from the deep.please suggest me some resource from where i can get help.suggest me something that will teach me from beginner level to pro level.I want to learn it from the root and also implement it in my line follower simultaneously. you can also suggest any good algorithm or control system for my line follower.it will be very kind of you.

Thanks in advance.you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for a long time.  I'm still struggling.  I've used a PID for my (RTK) line-following tractors so far.  They are barely good enough.  I'll try to describe generally how I did it.

1. Use a PID which varies in output from 0 to 90.
2. Calculate the cross-track distance (XTD).
3. Feed the PID with the XTD.
4. Use the output of the PID to determine the desired course.  0 means "head parallel with the line," and 90 means "head perpendicular toward the line."
5. Steer (using an IMU) to the desired course.

Sure, [it works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKPoWE57VNw), but I recommend [Pure Pursuit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5TRFLRXuuuA).

Comment: would you please tell me from where you learned PID?

Comment: I mostly learned about PID through making mistakes.  I'm not finding my favorite PID video right now but this tutorial [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vqWyramGy8] should give you a good start.